# How to READ the auto sleep time of pc from powercfg.exe (batch)

Tags: batch-file, sleep-mode, powercfg

I have a batch file that automatically sets the computer to sleep after 0 minutes (aka never sleep). Then I want to set it back to what it was before. My question is how would I set the current sleep time to a variable before I turn it off? Thanks in advance!

CLARIFICATION: I'm new to batch so feel free to point stuff out. Here's my current script:

```
@echo off
tasklist /v | find "Server" > nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    title Server
    set "time=[WHAT DO I PUT HERE?]" ::Gather current value for "put the computer to sleep:"
    C:
    cd C:windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0 ::Set the computer's sleep time to 0 (off)
    D:
    cd D:/Users/Elijah/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/ ::Do tasks
    java -Xmx12G -Xms10G -jar Tekkit.jar nogui
    cd C:windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac %time% ::When that's done, change the sleep setting back to what it was before we set it to 0
    title Server [STOPPED]
    pause
) else ( ::If bad stuff happens
    title Server [FAILED]
    echo A server is already running
    pause
)
```

I want to use this script for some automation with a Minecraft server. When I run a server from my computer, I have to change the "put the computer to sleep" setting to 0 minutes in control panel. I have already set this up in the script, but now my problem is turning auto-sleep back on and setting to what it was before. So to do that I want to store the value in a variable called `time`. How would I do that?

Comment: We need you batch code ! So [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39606633/edit) and post it !

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer:

Try out `powercfg -list`. This will provide a list of the energy-schemes that are saved on your computer. Copy the ID of the mode you need (if there is more than one). Next you want to get another ID: `powercfg -aliases` You will get a list of GUID's and text behind them. Look for `SUB_SLEEP` and copy that ID as well.
Now running the command `powercfg -q <1stID> <2ndID>` will output more lists where you want to look for something like `Sleep after`. Below that there should be values like `Possible Maximum` `Possible minimum` and further below in that block values for the current setting.

This is why it is a partial answer... I have no idea how to parse the output. But I am sure that someone else will help you with that :)